# pass data between content and menucontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a `menuViewController` and a `ContentViewController` using https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu. The MenuViewController contain a list of different leagues retrieved from local database. This contain a league object with following vars `leagueId` and `name`. When a league is selected it should send the data to the ContentViewController. However the problem is that the MenuViewController is not presenting the viewController it is just hiding the `menuViwController` and therefore i can't pass data from `menuViewController` to `contentViewController` when a cell with a league is selected. i've therefore tried to save the leagueId to a `NSUserDefault` key, however this creates a problem when the app is exited, since it wont reset the NSUserDefaults. What is the best approach for such issue? should i rethink it?

**pressing cell in menuViewController**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(menuArray![indexPath.row].id, forKey: "leagueId")


    self.sideMenuViewController.hideMenuViewController()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: did you even read the question @MacLean? this is not between two viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a global class, First create a global class, :-

```
  import Foundation


     class User {
      class var sharedInstance: User {
      struct Static {
           static var instance: User?
           static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
      }

     dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = User()
     }

     return Static.instance!

     }

    var leagueId: Int?
    var name:String?
  }
```

then store data in the class that you want

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    let user = User.sharedInstance


     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
            self.user.leagueId = Id
            self.user.name = Name
       } 
     }
   }
```

Then retrieve data :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

        let user = User.sharedInstance
        mylabel.text = self.user.leagueId 
        mylabael2.text = self.user.name
```

}